# The difference between Depends and decorator in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm exploring FastAPI. However, I can only partially understand the difference between `Depends` and decorator. For instance, when I want to protect a route, I can either write a decorator like `@auth_required` or using `Depends` to achieve this purpose.

Can anyone explain clearly the difference between these two? Like the mechanisms, the use cases to apply (when to use `Depends` or decorators).

Note: Some of my friends explain that `Depends` support caching while decorators don't. And decorators can add additional behaviors after executing the main function while `Depends` cannot.